# Problema al correr .jar en terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Estoy realizando un proyecto en eclipse. Al momento de exportar el programa por medio de la opción `RunnableJarfile`, realiza toda la exportación, lo guardo en mi escritorio y al momento de querer probarlo en mi computadora  por medio de la terminal a través de la siguiente instrucción:

`java -jar Cloud.jar` “192.168.0.0/24” “193.168.0.0/32”

en la terminal me sale este error: `Unable to accces jarfile Cloud.Jar`, lo que se encuenta entre paréntesis no importa, eso solo lo ocupa para llenar unos datos, ya traté de realizar el mismo procedimiento en otra computadora y me manda el mismo error.

Comment: Estas posicionado sobre la ruta del escritorio? si no es asi posicionate sobre el con el siguiente comando `cd C:\Users\myUser\Desktop` donde `myUser` es tu usuario de PC

Comment: Disculpame, verificaste que la opción `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` sea la seleccionada en el menú `Library handling` debajo de la ruta de exportación?

Comment: @j.Castro ese el problema muchas gracias .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ocurre que al momento de mandar a llamar al `.jar` no estas posicionado sobre la carpeta donde esta contenido el archivo. El error se soluciona diendo al directo donde se encuentra tu archivo de la siguiente manera:

`cd C:\Users\myUser\Desktop`

Donde `myUser` es el usuario de la PC.

Depues de eso ejecutar el `.jar` de la siguiente manera:

`java -jar Cloud.jar`